# trying to display a nested FormGroup with *ngFor, not sure how to access it

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I have a FormArray of FormGroups. Right now the FormArray, `experiences`, has one object, a FormGroup containing 3 controls, `companyName`, `jobDescription`, and `yearsWorked`. The problem is that when I console.log the FormArray object I see that the data object works like this: FormArray.controls.FormGroup.controls. I can't figure out what to call the FormGroup here so I can access it. So the html would be something like:

```
<div *ngFor="let exp of experiences.controls.[what do I call this?].controls"> 
    <input [formControlName]="n" placeholder="Experience"> 
</div>
```

The file itself can be seen [here](https://github.com/eugenehiggins/resume/blob/add-experience/src/app/homepage/experiences/test-formarray.component.ts#L15).

[image: Screenshot of my console.log object]

[Non-working plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/9Bhmw84b9TjbvExJl3U7?p=preview)

Comment: I'm not sure why it is a form array since it only contains one object? Are you planning to have more objects in the array? Or do you really only want a form group?

Comment: Right, I'm building this incrementally. There will be an arbitrary number of experiences. Supposed to be for a resume app.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

---

To continue on DeborahK's answer, so that we can achieve the solution you want to have, i.e having `experience` as an formArray, let's do the following and let's also look at your code. First error is here:

```html
<div *ngFor="let exp of experiences.controls.FormGroup.controls">
```

The iteration is wrong, it should simply be:

```html
<div *ngFor="let exp of experiences.controls; let n=index">
```

We need the index here, since you are having formgroups inside this array, so each has be named with the index.

<del>Then like DeborahK suggested, we need a pipe, because a your `expArray` is an object, and cannot be iterated with `*ngFor` without using a pipe.</del>

**UPDATE**: Since this question has been asked and answer written, angular provides `keyvalue` pipe, so there is no need to create a custom pipe:

```html
  <div formArrayName="experiences">
    <div *ngFor="let exp of experiences.controls; let n=index">
      <div [formGroupName]="n">
        <div *ngFor="let e of expArray | keyvalue">
          <input [formControlName]="e.key" placeholder="Experience">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-aabsb6?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: This is great, thanks. Had to step away because real work crunch time but this helped a lot. Now I'm going to try making expArray into an array of objects that will eventually be a Firebase call.

Comment: No problem, if you encounter any problems regarding this question, just holler and I'm happy to help if I can! :)

Comment: If I turn expArray into an array with one object, then later in the for...in I access that object using expArray[0], I would expect the output to work as your original example, but it does not: https://plnkr.co/edit/w5KUbE5IhCuqBqEJCMvN?p=preview. I get `ERROR Error: Cannot find control with path: 'experiences -> 0 -> 0'`.

Comment: Also it's maddening that ngOnInit runs twice if it doesn't like something in the template html :-\

Comment: Is experiences going to be an array with objects? Or is it only going to be those three properties inside one object? I would think not? Then each object should be wrapped in a formgroup. :)

Comment: This is the fixed, you need to make changes in template... iterate `let e of expArray[0] | keys` and in the for loop `fg[control] = new FormControl(this.expArray[0][control])` But I think you want to have a formArray, with different objects, so iteration cannot be done in template now as it is if that is the case... https://plnkr.co/edit/G7I3HZ9gGlVqjMs40FjX?p=preview

Comment: It's going to be an array with objects, each object would have those three properties

Comment: Okay, we need to change up the code a bit then and wrap each object in a formGroup. So is there going to be default values in them like there is now, or is it just going to be object key with empty field for user to fill in e.g yearsWorked? Just so that I know how to change the code :)

Comment: Hey I think I got it working! https://plnkr.co/edit/Zpz5wJfIqZOEiUKZMS6F?p=preview. EDIT: no I didn't, it's the right number of controls but it's just grabbing the last object, hm..

Comment: Ok NOW I got it working. I needed to re-initialize the fg object for each experience. Whew.

Comment: Haha, I was fighting the same thing, you were faster, thanks for letting me know why it wasn't working. Now I can sleep good tonight! :D

Comment: I totally broke this by having the original data object more closely resemble how the data would come from Firebase, and each object has a key. `expArray[n]` no longer works because `expArray` is no longer an array, and I don't know how to do a `for...in` loop in angular template syntax...should this be a new SO question?
EDIT: https://plnkr.co/edit/UGoDHg9AFtNPX4iBrGu3?p=preview

Comment: There ya go: https://plnkr.co/edit/9EeSx5MwqKo6vppb4O6j?p=preview It was easier fix than thought, you are already iterating the objects correctly, so all I did was change your template a bit! :) You can now just use the formControlNames in the template, no need for keys pipe :)

Comment: Whoops yeah, was totally overthinking it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I was able to get your Plunker to work by changing over to a FormGroup. You can see that solution here: https://plnkr.co/edit/AYeTzb2La6tBY4AqXXyx?p=preview

That at least gets you one step closer... Hopefully you'll be able to enhance it by adding the FormArray.

```
    <div formGroupName="experiences">
      <div *ngFor="let exp of expArray | keys">
          <input [formControlName]="exp" placeholder="Experience">
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Custom pipes are one of those things I learned about early on and promptly forgot. Thanks.